# Are the default copy constructors and assignment operator created for an abstract class in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, pure-virtual

There is a default copy-constructor/ assignment operator which does a shallow copy.
Are these created by default even for an abstract class?

Comment: Terminology: an **abstract** class is a class that has one or more **pure virtual** functions. There is no such thing as a pure virtual class.

Comment: Does the "pure virtual class" have data members?

Comment: As to the question, yes, these functions are generated; derived classes need them to implement copy constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - yes the class has member variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- implementation-wise, an abstract class has a vtable pointer.

Answer (score 5):

A class being *abstract* (ie, having *pure virtual* methods) doesn't change anything in regards to what the compiler may auto-generate for that class.  All it does is require the class to not be instantiated directly, and that its pure virtual methods must be overridden in derived classes.  That's it.  Abstract base classes must still be able to be initialized/assigned to, like any other class.